# Perl regex substitute everything not a float with space

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string and I want to substitute everything not a float of the form `x.x` but still keep exactly one space between each floating-point number:

```
 my $substitute_this = "ABC123  5.4 6.2  9.7    3.8   7.3";
 my $substitution =  $substitute_this =~ s/(some regex)/(something else?)/gr;
 print $substitution; #5.4 6.2 9.7 3.8 7.3
```

I do not really have a clue how to accomplish this, I know how to substitute floats:

```
 s/[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+//gr
```

and I know that to unmatch something in a character class I do something like

```
[^0-9]
```

But the regex for floating-point numbers is so long I don't know how to negate it. The second problem is to get only one space between every float, which I do not have a clue about how to accomplish.

Comment: Instead of using this cumbersome way, find each floating-point numbers and build a new string.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to extract all floats first:

```
my @floats = $substitute_this =~ /(?<!\S)([+-]?\d+\.\d+)(?!\S)/g;
```

and then join them into a single string:

```
print join(' ', @floats);
```

**Edit**: As Jiri Klouda points out below, this regular expression for floats is rather simplistic, but it's just an example. You can adjust it if you want. The point is that this approach let's you invert the logic of what you were trying to do, so that you don't have to try to match anything that *is not* a float (which is hard), but rather you just have to match anything that *is* a float.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s10.html

Comment: I don't think that would correctly handle something slightly malformed this way `1.23.4`

Comment: @shawnt00 I added a `\b` to address that.

Comment: Adding `\b` doesn't prevent to find a match in  `1.23.4`, you need something stronger.

Comment: I changed the 2 `\b` into a `(?:\A|\s)` and `(?:\z|\s)`, hopefully that should do it.

Comment: I did consider using zero-width assertions, but I think there is not reason here. They are usually slower.

Comment: Your pattern, as it stands, doesn't match 6.2 in the original problem. So...? And a word boundary *is* a zero-width assertion.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @redneb solution, a one-go RegEx would be like this:

```
\d++\.\d++(?= +|\Z)(*SKIP)(?!)|[^\s]+ *|\s(?=\s)
```

Perl:

```
echo "5.23 ABC123  5.4 6.2965  9.7    3.8   7.3 5.3.3 ABC.2356" | perl -ne "s/\d++\.\d++(?= +|\Z)(*SKIP)(?!)|[^\s]+ *|\s(?=\s)//g; print;"
```

Output:

```
5.23 5.4 6.2965 9.7 3.8 7.3
```

[Live demo](http://fiddle.re/qkey3a) (Use global match and replace with nothing)

Comment: Nice, but I got a `"variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex (regex)"` error. It seems it comes from the first part in the regex: `(?<=\s|\A)\d+`. I tried to change this to `((?<=\s)\d+|(?<=\A)\d+)` but then I got the output `(lots of spaces) 3.8 7.3`.

Comment: You were right. Please check update and live demo. @hampadampadoo

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a global regex pattern match to finds all floating-point numbers—optional sign, digits, dot, digits—that are neither preceded nor followed by a non-space character. The resulting list is simply joined using spaces and returned to the original variable

I can't tell whether you have any numbers in any other format (without a decimal point, for instance) but you say *"substitute everything not a float of the form x.x"* so that is what I have coded, with the addition of the optional sign character which you mention later

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = "ABC123  5.4 6.2  9.7    3.8   7.3";

$s = join ' ', $s =~ / (?<!\S) [+-]? \d+ \. \d+ (?!\S) /xg;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
5.4 6.2 9.7 3.8 7.3
```

Comment: How is this different than the solution that was posted four hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this problem with [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) over your list:

```perl
sub extract_float {
  # split string with null char (\s+)
  my @array = split(/\s+/, shift);

  # anonymous function who return string only if 
  # arguments is in form `integer.integer`
  my $fun = sub { $_ =~ !\d+\.\d+! };

  # map $fun on @array
  my @map = map(&$fun, @array);

  # convert @array in string (each value separated with space)
  join(" ", @map);
}

sub extract_float_oneline {
  join(" ", map({$_ =~ /(\d+\.\d+)/} split(/\s+/, shift)));
}

my $string = "ABC123  5.4 6.2  9.7    3.8   7.3";
print extract_float($string)."\n";
# 5.4 6.2 9.7 3.8 7.3

print extract_float_oneline($string)."\n";
# 5.4 6.2 9.7 3.8 7.3
```